# How to fix different behaviour for find_element in frame between Selenium IDE and Python Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, ide

I would like to implement the following commands which already work in the Selenium IDE (screenshot) to python (see coding).

https://i.ibb.co/ydMWN1R/selenium.png

```
driver.get("https://www.luckyemoji.com/logout");
driver.get("https://www.luckyemoji.com/login");
element = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
element.send_keys('#####')
element = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
element.send_keys('#####')
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span/div[3]").click()
```

Following error occours:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span/div[3]"}
(Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.121)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.35 (0),platform=Linux 4.14.98-v7+ armv7l)

Answer (score 0):

That means, that you are trying to click an element that isnt existing, if you go to the website, do you know wich button you are trying to click?
If you can show me this button, I could help you.

PS: may add another screenshot

PPS: there is a captcha, so you arent enable to enter this competition with a bot (if you are trying to make like 1000 accounts to win money ;D )

Edit:
To get the working xpath, go on the website, press F12, click on the icon in the top left corner (at the window that popped up), than click on the button(the button that the program should click), then right click the thing that is marked at the right side of your screen, then click copy -> xpath

Hope you can understand that xP

Comment: hehe, I only have one account to make the big money. - how comes that the selenium ide procedure is working? https://i.ibb.co/ydMWN1R/selenium.png both are "non headless"

Comment: Is it working now, or was it working before (maybe it is outdated?)

Comment: Mhm I don't know why, but I can help you to get python working.... wait a sec and I update my Answer

Comment: Now I added a edit part to my answer, that you can see how to get the working xpath

Comment: thanks for your answer LaPeSi but it's the exact correct xpath which also works when using the selenium ide - here you see it's marked green:
https://i.ibb.co/ydMWN1R/selenium.png
but when using find_element_by_xpath in combination with switch_to.frame I get this error and don't know why...

Comment: mhm, can you show me what you are trying to do, then I can help you to write a working script on python

Comment: I cant find the button you are trying to click..... you can also try to get the button by id or sth like that [driver.find_element_by_id('submit')]

Comment: hmhm I think you are misunderstanding me... 
I know the correct XPath because otherwise it won't be working when using the Selenium IDE, the XPath within the iframe 0 is:
   //span/div[3]
For me the relevant question is: Why is it working in selenium ide and not with python webdriver, you know?

Comment: Oh I think it isn't working because you did the driver.switch_to.frame wrong, I googled it and it says you have to use the name of the frame and not the number